# Conditional formatted sections not playing well with browsers

Tags: infopath

I've got a form with four conditional sections based on checkbox controls. For whatever reason, the 'hide this control' rules quit working in IE but still work just fine in Chrome browsers.

The four sections were formerly contained within a single large section, which opened on choice of a dropdown selection at the top of the form. Our team decided to abandon the one-hide thing and go with four separate sections all controlled by independent checkboxes. When I put the thing back together I had no response from my checkboxes in IE.

I have no idea what plug I tripped over but this has got an entire project on hold until I find an answer. Nowhere online has yielded anything I can use or shed any light on why this happened.